# How to plot polygon in R from coordinates string?

Tags: r, coordinates, spatial-database, spatial-statistics

So I extracted the boundaries from DBSCAN in python and am now working on R to create visualization in GGPLOT and LEAFLET but I can't get the polygons to plot. This is a sample of the data:

> [1,] "[(-98.898765, 19.455622), (-98.90185646, 19.44840652),
>   (-98.91575986, 19.45534196), (-98.91887031, 19.46230492),
>   (-98.91900371, 19.46275993), (-98.89589915, 19.46653405),
>   (-98.89548853, 19.46623211), (-98.89525595, 19.46604594), (-98.897175,
>   19.45978824), (-98.898765, 19.455622)]"
>
> [2,] "[(-98.84953814, 19.55776871), (-98.86278253, 19.55505466),
>   (-98.86600973, 19.56443923), (-98.86597848, 19.56479789),
>   (-98.86202303, 19.57997289), (-98.85983876, 19.58694556),
>   (-98.84350132, 19.59316276), (-98.84325275, 19.59280415),
>   (-98.83970199, 19.58690075), (-98.83834813, 19.58301972),
>   (-98.84953814, 19.55776871)]"

I'm guessing I have to extract each number to create separate columns for latitude and longitude and be able to run the ggplot?
I've tried to split it, extract it, and many more methods but getting various errors for example:

> Error in UseMethod("extract_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'extract_' applied to an object of class "factor"

I've tried to do it on one cell only to get grips first but negative results always.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I continued this thread in this link, with follow-ups
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252040/plot-categorical-leaflet-polygons-from-a-csv-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### To plot your coordinate string on Leaflet in R:

Include the leaflet library:

`install.packages('leaflet')
 library('leaflet')`

Assign original string to a variable:

`s1 <- "[(-98.898765, 19.455622), (-98.90185646, 19.44840652), (-98.91575986, 19.45534196), (-98.91887031, 19.46230492), (-98.91900371, 19.46275993), (-98.89589915, 19.46653405), (-98.89548853, 19.46623211), (-98.89525595, 19.46604594), (-98.897175, 19.45978824), (-98.898765, 19.455622)]"`

Strip out unwanted characters:

`c1 <- chartr('()[]','    ', s1)`

Turn the cleaned string into a two column matix (Like [@Spacedman](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/865/spacedman) said):

`m1 <- matrix(as.numeric(strsplit(c1,",")[[1]]),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)`

make the Leaflet map and plot it:

`map <- leaflet()
 map <- addTiles(map)
 map <- addPolygons(map, data = m1, color = "blue", weight = 4, 
          smoothFactor = 0.5,opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,fillColor = 'red')
 map`

You could also use [SpatialPolygons like this past answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/18313/2512) to a similar question.

Comment: Thank you Paul! this was a step ahead though.. what about plotting many polygons in the same map?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a string like this:

```
> s
[1] "[(-98.898765, 19.455622), (-98.90185646, 19.44840652), (-98.91575986, 19.45534196), (-98.91887031, 19.46230492), (-98.91900371, 19.46275993), (-98.89589915, 19.46653405), (-98.89548853, 19.46623211), (-98.89525595, 19.46604594), (-98.897175, 19.45978824), (-98.898765, 19.455622)]"
```

If you replace all the different brackets with spaces using `chartr`, then you are left with a comma-separated string you can split with `strsplit`, and then convert to a 2-column matrix:

```
> matrix(as.numeric(strsplit(chartr('([)]','    ',s),",")[[1]]),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
           [,1]     [,2]
 [1,] -98.89876 19.45562
 [2,] -98.90186 19.44841
 [3,] -98.91576 19.45534
 [4,] -98.91887 19.46230
 [5,] -98.91900 19.46276
 [6,] -98.89590 19.46653
 [7,] -98.89549 19.46623
 [8,] -98.89526 19.46605
 [9,] -98.89718 19.45979
[10,] -98.89876 19.45562
```