# Plot Categorical Leaflet Polygons from a csv in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I want to plot each polygon with the color stated in the column 'Categories' in the dataframe 'new'

This is what the dataframe 'new' looks like:

[image: data]

```
palcat <- colorFactor(new$Categories)

## to delete the special characters in each polygon value (new$Polygon)
new$Polygon <- chartr('()[]','    ', new$Polygon)

#subset Polygon column
blocks <- new$Polygon

####          PLOT TO LEAFLET          ####
map <- leaflet()


counter <- 1

for(i in blocks){
  m <- matrix(as.numeric(strsplit(blocks,",")[[counter]]),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
  palcat <- colorFactor(viridis(20), new$Categories)
  map <- addPolygons(map, data = m, color = 'black', weight = 0.25,
                     smoothFactor = 0.5,opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.1,fillColor = ~palcat(Categories))

  counter <- counter + 1
}

# map %>%  addPolygons(new$Polygon, fillColor = colorFactor(new$Categories))
map
map %>% addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron)
```

If you change the color directly in fillColor = "blue", it works

```
    fillColor = colorFactor(new$Categories))
```

inside the addPolygon part but since it's inside the loop that turns each Polygon Cell to a Matrix its not working. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an id so that your function `fillcolor` know which color of the vector is to be used. I proposed a reproducible example as you did not provide your own data:

```
# Create a polygons
xy = cbind(
  x = c(13.4, 13.4, 13.6, 13.6, 13.4),
  y = c(48.9, 49, 49, 48.9, 48.9)
    )

# Create blocks as in your data
blocks <- c(paste(c(t(xy)), collapse = ", "), paste(c(t(xy+0.1)), collapse = ", "))
```

[image: blocks]

```
# Create vector of colors like your categories
fillColor <- c("blue", "red")
# Create id
id <- 1:2

map <- leaflet()
counter <- 1
for(i in blocks){
  m <- matrix(as.numeric(strsplit(blocks,",")[[counter]]),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
  map <- addPolygons(map, data = m, color = 'black', weight = 0.25,
                     smoothFactor = 0.5,opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.1, 
                     fillColor = fillColor[id[counter]])
  counter <- counter + 1
}
map
```

[image: leaflet output]

I did a blog article on [multiple polygons in a loop with leaflet](https://statnmap.com/multiple-layers-leaflet-widget-with-rstat/) if needed.

Edit: Be careful when using color names, they should exist in html/css. Otherwise, you should better use hexa code.

So, doing that with your dataset should be:

```
# Create vector of colors like your categories
fillColor <- new$Categories
# Create id
id <- 1:nrow(new)

map <- leaflet()
counter <- 1
for(i in blocks){
  m <- matrix(as.numeric(strsplit(blocks,",")[[counter]]),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
  map <- addPolygons(map, data = m, color = 'black', weight = 0.25,
                     smoothFactor = 0.5,opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.1, 
                     fillColor = fillColor[id[counter]])
  counter <- counter + 1
}
map
```

If you still have problems, this may be in your dataset. In that case, you will need to share it.

Comment: Thanks StatnMap! it still givesout an error though: `Error in UseMethod("metaData") : 
  no applicable method for 'metaData' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')" `

Comment: I edited my answer with a working reproducible example. If you still have problems, you'll need to share your data.